# Как плавно развернуться лицом к врагу

Tags: c#, unity3d

Здравствуйте. Не так давно я начал изучать Unity3d.

Столкнулся с проблемой. Не смог найти ее решение на просторах интернета.
Проект мой, что-то типа стратегии. Все передвижения пкм. Удар наносится на Fire1. Урон наносится за счет триггера. Поэтому, когда подхожу к врагу, он также бежит на меня. Может оббежать с другой стороны. Тогда я не буду попадать по нему. Для этого я написал простенький скрипт, который разворачивает персонажа к врагу, на которого кликнули пкм. Вот он

```
void Update () {

    if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if(Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity))
            if(hit.collider.CompareTag("Enemy") )
            {
                transform.LookAt(hit.transform.position);
            }
    }

}
```

Дело в том, что он вращает персонажа лицом к врагу, словно телепортирует. Особенно это не очень смотрится, когда ты стоишь далеко от врага.

Хотел бы узнать, как развернуть перса медленно. Если можно, с объяснениями. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: steering behavior поищите в поисковике. Узнаете много интересного

Comment: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/492508/c-enemy-ai-rotation.html  .......... http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/666635/rotate-enemy-towards-player-character.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Держи!**

```
    [Range(0,20)]
    public float speed;
    Vector3 direction;

    void Update()
    {
         if (Input.GetMouseButton(1)) {
            RaycastHit hit;
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity))
                if (hit.collider.CompareTag("Enemy")) {
                    //transform.LookAt(hit.transform.position);
                    direction = transform.position - hit.transform.position;
                    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(direction), Time.deltaTime * speed);
                }
         }   
    }
```